# ConstraintLayout center align image and text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

how can I align `TextView` to end of `ImageView` that `TextView` would be `centered vertically` using `ConstraintLayout` I managed to align it to the end of `ImageView` but it's not centered vertically because `ImageView` is a bit bigger than `TextView` I know how to do it using `RelativeLayout`, but wanna use best practices and use only `ConstraintLayout`

Here is an example how it should look (Cloud icon and text Last Backup)

[image]

Comment: Please upload XML file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` together, and it will cause the `TextView` center vertical align to the `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Last Backup"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    />
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `drawable` left for your TextView like this and change `gravity` by your root `layout` as you want

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawablePadding="15dp"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/google"
     android:text="@string/textGoogle" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do like in using ConstraintLayout:**

Set Textview top and bottom constrain to ImageView top and bottom.
These constraints will set TextView in center of ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_icon"/>


 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageview"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageview"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageview"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set parent constrain end top and bottom. These constraints will set center of constrain
       `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImg"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtlbResult"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtlbResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text14sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:text="@string/your_result_are_here"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivImg"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```